# Is it possible to set the Switch connecting Server's interface to trunk mode?

Tags: networking, switch

Whether the Switch interface connect to Server can be set to trunk?

[image]

I have a question, in general the Server A connect to Switch's interface is access. and the interface must set one VLAN.

so I have an idea, I want to set the interface to trunk, so there can be have multi VLANs, and the Server B can be set multi IP address which are not in one VLAN.

I don't know whether this is possible, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLAN tags are just extra bytes inside the Ethernet frame, so it's possible as long as the server OS knows how to interpret them. (If in doubt, search for "<os_name> 802.1Q vlan".)

- Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris 11 have native support for tagged VLANs, so you can use a trunk/mixed port and create a virtual interface for each VLAN. It's usually as simple as `ip link add`.
- Windows does not support multiple VLANs natively. Only some server-grade Ethernet cards (Intel, Mellanox, etc.) come with Windows drivers which provide custom virtual interfaces for VLANs.
- Hyper-V Virtual Switch on Windows Server *does* support VLANs and can assign access/trunk ports for each virtual machine, just like on real switch. (Trunk and mixed modes are available through PowerShell.) However, it still doesn't allow the host OS itself to connect to more than one VLAN.
- Many other virtual machine software (such as ESXi/vSphere) also have built-in VLAN tagging support, and can assign each VM to a specific VLAN.

For best results, the Ethernet card should support hardware-based VLAN tagging or at least larger frame sizes (1522 bytes, so that the OS could use the standard 1500 MTU even with the tag added). Most modern Ethernet NICs should do the job.

Comment: Hi, friend. the `Linux, FreeBSD, etc. have native support for tagged VLANs, so you can use a trunk/mixed port and create a virtual interface for each VLAN`, how to understand the `create a virtual interface for each VLAN`? do you mean create l3 interface?

Comment: It behaves exactly the same way as physical eth0/en0 interface; i.e. you can use it for IP as well as send raw Ethernet frames. (For example, `ip link add eth0.11 link eth0 type vlan id 11` on Linux would create such a virtual interface based on the physical interface "eth0" and VLAN ID 11. Then you add an IP address to it like on a normal interface, or run dhcp.)